# Display text center screen

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Hey guys, I need to display a message in a flash project I'm working on.  The message needs to be centered on screen, and can only be created using code.

Normally I could just put a dynamic text box on and hide it, but I can't this time.

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a class that has a textfield centered within it. Then create a new instance when you need to display a message and add it to the stage. Here is a very simplified example:

```
package
{
     import flash.display.Sprite;
     import flash.text.TextField;
     import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

     public class Message extends Sprite {

          private var tf:TextField;
          private var s:Sprite;

          public function Message(msg:String) {
               s = new Sprite();
               s.graphics.beginFill(0,0);
               s.graphics.drawRect(0,0,800,600);
               s.graphics.endFill();
               addChild(s);

               tf = new TextField();
               tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
               tf.width = 400;
               tf.text = msg;
               tf.x = (s.width-tf.textWidth)*0.5;
               tf.y = (s.height-tf.textHeight)*0.5;
               addChild(tf);
          }
     }
}
```

I would add other functions to this and maybe even add a resize listener to keep it centered. You could also add a few buttons to close the message. The sprite is added only to disable any mouse clicks beneath the message. Does that help?

Comment: Actually about the above code, it's good except, if the auto-size on on center you just need to put the x/y to stage.stageWidth * .5 and stage.stageHeight * .5 without setting the width property of the text field, or setting it to 0. Then after performing these transformations, set the text property. This will be perfectly centered. The only minor adjustment you'd have to do is add textField.textHeight * .5 to the y property of the text field to have the text centered exactly in the middle.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the "800x600" rectangle should be the width and height of your stage. The only reason I didn't put stage.stageWidth etc. is that from the constructor function of this class, stage does not yet exist. You could either pass in the width/height through the parameters, or add an "ADDED_TO_STAGE" event listener, then resize according to the stage width/height. Again, this is a very simplified class, but as @Ascension Systems pointed out, you can just use auto size center to center the field.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically centering content in Flash is pretty straight forward; the properties stage.stageWidth and stage.stageHeight can be used to determined the size of the Flash Player's canvas.  All DisplayObject's attached to the displayList have access to the stage property; the only gotcha is that this property will be null in the constructor function as it won't have been added to the displayList yet; however, we can easily work around that with an Event Listener:

```
public class AutoStageCenterSprite extends Sprite
{
    public function AutoStageCenterSprite()
    {
        if (stage == null) {
            // Wait to be added to Stage before we activate the Resize Listener.
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStageEvent);
        }
        else {
            centerOnStage();
        }
    }

    private function onAddedToStageEvent(event : Event) : void
    {
        // Now we've been added we can center ourselves...
        centerOnStage();

        // We will also register for Resize  Events so we can update our position
        // is the Stage dimensions change.
        stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onResizeEvent);
    }

    private function centerOnStage() : void
    {
        x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - (width / 2);
        y = (stage.stageHeight / 2) - (height / 2);
    }

    private function onResizeEvent(event : Event) : void
    {
        // This event listener will be tripped each the Stage is resized.
        if (stage != null) {
            centerOnStage();
        }
    }
}
```

The next part of your question deals with how to add a TextField to the equation.  [The Flash TextField API](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html).  You could either choose to extend the TextField class and add the centering code; or use composition instead and create a new TextField instance inside you AutoStageCenterSprite.